# How can I compare two tables and return the matched value into one row

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I have two tables in different sheet (Sheet1 & Sheet2) to compare and match the content and return the result to Sheet3. There are two type of criteria should be match of:

*1st. criteria - combination of Col A, B , C,& D*

If combination of this column (A,B,C,D) in Sheet1 unmatch with combination of this column (A,B,C,D) in Sheet2, the result in Sheet3 should be like shown below. If matched it will be populated into the same row and marked as "match", but if not match it will not be populated into one row and marked as "unmatch".

[image: 1st criteria]

*2nd. criteria - compare value of column E of matched list on the 1st criteria*

Continue from 1st criteria. Next I need to compare the value of column E. If the value is matched it should be marked as "match", but if not match t should be marked as "unmatch" and the value should be highlited. as shown below

[image: 2nd criteria]

Do I need a VB script to do this? I'm very very new in VB script.

Comment: Provided the two tables are sorted by Col D (Cols B+C are part of it and Col A looks like a constant) your resulting table has a block with greater values leading which seems inconsistent, every algorythm will copy rows until an equal / lower value found and then swap to the other table.